# Google Cloud Function triggering event for database write

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use the web interface to the Google Cloud Functions (https://console.cloud.google.com) to test a cloud function.  On the testing tab there is a 'Triggering event' field that expects a JSON string.  The function I am testing is triggered by a database write, but I don't know what data I should enter in this field for testing purposes.

My function is triggered by the following:

> Trigger type
>
> Firebase Database: write Event type
>
> providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.write

Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: We don't currently have support for using the Cloud console to test Realtime Database functions. There is some active work happening to make the story better here, but nothing to announce just yet.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Can you provide that as an answer? Though not always popular, "no" is sometimes a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support or documentation for using the Cloud console to test Realtime Database functions. There is active work happening to make the testing / debugging story better, but nothing to announce at this time.